# A program which calculate factorial from 1-9 by iteration

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program which can calculate factorial from 1-9 by iteration, but I encounter some problems while I am trying to. Please help me figure out my problems in my program, I am just learning programming.

The following is my program, please tell me what's wrong with it:

```
public class iterative {
    static int ans=1;
    public static void iteration() {
        System.out.println("n n!");

        for (int n=1; n<10; n++) {
            while ((n-1)>0)
                ans=n*(n-1);
            System.out.println(n + " " + ans);
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        iteration();
    }
}
```

Comment: How about you tell us what the problems are? We aren't here to do your homework, we are here to help. Ask specific questions.

Comment: Is this for a homework assignment? Its fine if it is, but generally you should be upfront about it. People will give you more hint-like answers, rather than just give the answer, to help you learn the material.  Also, what errors are you getting? The more specific you can be, the more helpful we can be.

Comment: Your second println should give you a hint. What is the value of ans in each iteration? What do you expect it to be?

Comment: Well this isn't my homework assignment, I just trying some practice on my own and find out some problems.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers above is close perfect,you also get it with the recursion:
here is code:

```
public class iterative {

    public static int iteration(int n) {
        int result;
        if(n==1)return n;
        else
        result = n*iteration(n-1);
     return result;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Result is :" + iteration(9));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't use a static for `ans`. A local is what you want.

Secondly the factorial recurrence relationship you use is incorrect. You should do it like this.

```
int ans = 1;
for (int n=1; n<=9; n++) {
    ans = ans*n;
    System.out.println(n + " " + ans);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see three big problems.

Firstly, "ans" is global and is never reassigned. So over time it will display an accumulated incorrect value.

The other is that the while loop will run forever for n > 1.

Lastly, the recurrence relationship is wrong. Should be ans = ans * (n-1). See code.

The fact that you have nested loops suggests to me that you are trying to print a table of factorials.

Try this:

```
for (int n=1; n<10; n++) {
    int ans = 1;
    int x = 0;
    while ((n-x)>0){
        ans=ans*(n-x);
        x++;
    }  
    System.out.println(n + " " + ans);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm needed work as well:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
         int i = 1;
         while(i < 10)
            iteration(i++);
    }

    public static void iteration(int max) {
        System.out.println("n n!");
        int ans = 1;
        for (int n=1; n<=max; n++) {
            ans *= n;       
      }
      System.out.println(" " + ans);
}
```

[ideone example](http://ideone.com/hy7x8)

Answer (score 0):

Like @David's solution but shorter

```
for(int i=1, ans=1; i <= 9; i++, ans *= i)
   System.out.println(i + " " + ans);
```